# Solve $x^{(4)}+6x^{(2)}+25x=t\sinh t\cos (2t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve following differential equation:
$$
x^{(4)}+6x^{(2)}+25x=t\sinh t\cos (2t)
$$

Well, my idea was first to transform this equation into equation in complex numbers in order to remove trigonometric funtions. But the best I was able to do was:
$$
z^{(4)}+6z^{(2)}+25z=te^{\ln(\sinh t)+2it}
$$
And then of course real part of this equastion is what we need to solve. The only method I know, which allows to solve it needs firstly to find solutions of $\lambda^4+6\lambda^2+25\lambda=0$. And I do not see the way to do this.

Anyway Wolfram gives pretty complicated result, although homogeneous part looks nice.

Comment: The answer from WA is *a pretty complicated result*, I totally agree. However, it does simplify a lot.

Comment: Using the highest and lowest degree term to start the quadratic completion, one gets $r^4+6r^2+25=(r^2+5)^2-4r^2=((r-1)^2+4)((r+1)^2+4)$, which should be an easier form to read off the roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homogeneous part is easy enough: the characteristic polynomial is a quartic polynomial of "quadratic type" meaning that it can be reduced $u^2+6u+25$ under the substitution $u=x^2$. So the roots of this are $\pm \sqrt{r_1}$ and $\pm \sqrt{r_2}$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the (complex) roots of $u^2+6u+25$.

The inhomogeneous part is better handled by splitting the sinh into its exponential components. Then $t \sinh(t) \cos(2t) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Re} \left ( t e^{(1+2i)t} + t e^{(-1+2i)t} \right )$. Each of the terms on the inside of the real part is now routine (albeit messy) to handle, being a product of a polynomial and a complex exponential.